# materail-react-table using renderRowActions Resize

Tags: material-react-table

I want to resize only that specific column

[Material-react-table using renderRowActions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx337.png)

```
        <MaterialReactTable
            columns={columns}
            data={data ?? []}
            initialState={{ 
                density: 'compact',
                columnPinning: { 
                    right: ['mrt-row-actions'] 
                }
            }} 
            // positionActionsColumn={'last'}
            enableRowActions
            renderRowActions={renderRowActions}
            state={{
                isLoading:isLoading
            }}
        />
```

using pinning => (mrt-row-actions)

How to resize? because we are not defining column_def for this row-action

Where to add size - name of props

Answer (score 1):

displayColumnDefOptions: {
'mrt-row-actions': {
header: 'Change Account Settings', //change header text
size: 200, //make actions column wider
},
}